# Open VB Form in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, html

I am making a web based chat application

I have a list of users and want to open my chat window using:

```
<a href="#chatCreate:{user}" target="_NEW"></a>
```

This opens the chat window as I wanted, but also open Internet Explorer, is there a way to prevent this

In my application I am using:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    ChatWindow.Show()
End Sub
```